# Preciso de um código que dê o erro AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, .net, exceção

Meu professor passou uma série de exercícios  e neles eu preciso criar um código para dar o erro `AccessViolationException`. Porém não estou conseguindo criar um código que de esse erro (não estou querendo fazer o tratamento do erro).

Preciso de algo para inserir dentro do `try`.

```
try{
    //código que retorna o erro 
}catch(AccessViolationException ex){
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Comment: Dá um `System.IO.Directory.DeleteDirectory("C:\\Windows\\System32");` e você terá um `AccessViolationException` (além de outras surpresinhas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código abaixo consistentemente gera uma exceção do tipo `AccessViolationException`:

```
var ptr = new IntPtr(42);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(42, ptr, true);
```

Isso dito, a resposta de @Maniero está correta. Não há nenhum aspecto de `throw new AccessViolationException()` que gere um comportamento diferente.

Fonte:
[How to test handling of AccessViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839615/how-to-test-handling-of-accessviolationexception)

Answer (score 6):

É simples:

```
try {
    throw new AccessViolationException();
} catch (AccessViolationException ex){
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pkMYa3). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dWx0rX). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://ideone.com/pkMYa3).

Não estava na pergunta que não podia usar `throw`. Essas regras fictícias não servem pra nada. A única utilidade que vejo para simular o erro é fazer testes e isto pode ser feito com o `throw`.

Há uma [pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10839615/221800) que trata disto com resposta de quem entende bem, mas não sei se funciona.

Comment: Não posso utilizar throw

Comment: Olha, tecnicamente, errado não tá.